Can intellij stop at breakpoints from different modules?
I created a standard gradle project, which created a main and a test module.

I put my tests in the test module, and they call the code which is in main module:

But if I set breakpoints, they only work in the test module, the main module breakpoints are ignored, is it possible to make them work somehow?
UPD: after a bit of digging it turns out that the problem happens because of gradle scala plugin, if I write my unit tests in Java, they work properly.
